# how to setup order process

Tags: orders, magento-community

when the customer order t-shirts for team or event this is the step I want

1- select color
2-select size and quantity  for example s=2,M=1,X=4,XL=2 at same time
3- add order to cart

something like this http://www.4imprint.ca/product/C121147-L

Comment: Please try to clarify your question, it's not clear what about you are asking.

Comment: did you see 4 imprint order process?I am trying to create something like it

Answer (score 0):

From your query what i understood that you are looking for following product option

**1)Color**

**2)Size**

For this you have 2 options in Magento

1)Use custom option for simple product

2)Use configurable product

Answer (score 0):

The way to go here is to use custom options. This allows a user to define specific options before he presses the `add to cart` button (like on your example page). Those, however, are all shown at once in Magento as you get it when you first set it up.

The part where you can click through the options as on the example site you linked to is a little more complex. Since you're asking such a broad question, I'll answer quite broadly for now as well:

- Use a custom **JavaScript** snippet and include it in the template where the custom options are rendered. This snippet would just hide every option but the one the customer is currently entering data for. After the last one, you show the `add to cart` button to allow the customer to send the request to the server.
- "**ajaxify**" the site. Which would mean not rendering all options but the first in the php template already (not even sending them to the customer) and then making an `AJAX` request once the user presses `continue`

The latter one of these is certainly the more elegant and flexible of the two because it doesn't rely on you having *exactly* the right options on each product. The second one allows for modularity and can easily applied to other products with different options as well.

---

**Update**: as Suman-PHP4U mentioned in his answer, you can achieve the same thing using configurable products. The JavaScript / AJAX part I was talking about and which seems to be an *essential* part of your question is roughly the same.